# Set variables and use them for output in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table which has the regular information about products. Another table has pricing information and both tables are 1:n related. So every product may have (at least) 1 to n prices.

Now I need to display some of those prices in a view together with the product. Also to form some rows I have to add or multiply some of these prices.

In my first attempt I used sub-queries for the output and the operation. Which works, but the performance is... meh...
I thought about using variables to set the pricing-values one time and just reuse them. It would be even better if I'd be able to set 2 or more variables at once. But how?

My basic query looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT ProductNr,
Description,
Year, ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
(PARTITION BY ProductNr ORDER BY Year DESC) RowRank
          FROM Products
     WHERE Year like '2014'
     AND Manager = 1
     )sub
    WHERE RowRank = 1
```

A sub-query is basically set up like this:

```
(SELECT Price FROM PricingInfo
WHERE Manager = 1
AND year = Products.Year
AND no = 1
AND ArticleNr = Products.ProductNr)
```

I made an attempt by using

```
DECLARE @price float
-- other ones...

SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT ProductNr,
Description,
@price = (SELECT colXX FROM PricingInfo
          WHERE Manager = 1
          AND year = products.Year
          AND row = 'Y'
          AND ArticleNr = products.ProductNr),
@price*1.2 as PriceWithTax
Year, ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
(PARTITION BY ProductNr ORDER BY Year DESC) RowRank
          FROM Products products
     WHERE Year like '2014'
     AND Manager = 1
     )sub
    WHERE RowRank = 1
```

Is this possible to use a construct like that?

EDIT [21:09] - @MatBailie requested some examples:

```
ProductNr|Description|Year
      001| Teddy Bear|2012
      002|  Card game|2013
      003|       Book|2012
      003|       Book|2013
```

The Pricing-Information:

```
Category|No|Price|Notice| ID|Year
1       |1 |35,22|No Tax|001|2012
1       |2 |38,18|Tax   |001|2012
1       |3 |19,91|Bought|001|2012
1       |1 |19,91|Bought|002|2013
```

Comment: Could you show some example input and output data?  I'm pretty sure there are simpler methods to accomplish what you need,but I'm not completely clear on your functional requirement.  Is it just a case of "get the most recent price for each product", then show it both as-is and also multiplied by 1.2?

Comment: @MatBailie: Added them :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a parameter, you could try joining both tables and then using the values of the joined table on the previous one.

```
SELECT *
    FROM (    
    SELECT  P.ProductNr,
                P.Description,
                PInfo.Price,
                PInfo.Price*1.2 as PriceWithTax
                P.Year, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P.ProductNr ORDER BY P.Year DESC) RowRank
        FROM Products P
        INNER JOIN (SELECT  ArticleNr, 
                            Year, 
                            colXX [Price]
                    FROM    PricingInfo
                    WHERE   Manager = 1
                            AND row = 'Y') PInfo
            ON P.ProductNr = PInfo.ArticleNr
            AND P.Year = PInfo.Year
        WHERE   Year = '2014'
                AND Manager = 1
    ) SUB
    WHERE SUB.RowRank = 1
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the idea.
Actually I haven't thought of a solution like that yet. To be honest I have to add I'm pretty bad in using variables in queries, so the solution to this problem would help me a lot to understand how to use them

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT Products.ProductNr
      ,Products.[Description]
      ,P_Info.colXX     AS Price
      ,P_Info.colXX * 1.2  AS PriceWithTax
      ,P.[Year]
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P_Info.ProductNr ORDER BY P_Info.[Year] DESC) RowRank
FROM Products P INNER JOIN PricingInfo P_Info
ON P.ProductNr = P_Info.ArticleNr
WHERE P.[Year] LIKE '2014' AND P_Info.[Year] LIKE '2014'
AND   P.Manager = 1  AND P_Info.Manager = 1
AND   P_Info.[ROW] = 'Y'
)Q
WHERE RowRank = 1
```

Comment: The same as for @magnusw above: I haven't thought of that yet, but I'd like to get better in using variables